# Issues with cross-correlation function (ccf) to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, cross-correlation

I am using the cross-correlation function (ccf) to show day lags in discharge from different springs. I used [ccf to ggplot code](https://gist.github.com/martinctc/4afa64602b68d8895f14386169598b1a) for better visualization. My results looked like the image below and the code worked flawlessly, but then I went to re-run the code and now I keep getting an error. I had originally modified the source code slightly, but once I had the error, I went back to the original source code and the error persists!

## Data, code and problem:

```
# example data   
big = runif(60)
mangum = runif(61:120)
hydro = data.frame(big, mangum)

# Using the ccf to ggplot function (from the above link)
xcf_plot <- function(df, x, y, title = "Cross Correlation"){
  df_x <- eval(substitute(x), df)
  df_y <- eval(substitute(y), df)
  ccf.object <- ccf(df_x, df_y, plot = FALSE)
  output_table <- cbind(lag = ccf.object$lag, 
                        x.corr = ccf.object$acf) %>%
                          as_tibble() %>%
                          mutate(cat = ifelse(x.corr > 0, "green", "red"))
  output_table %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = lag, y = x.corr)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = cat))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#339933", "#cc0000"))+
    ylab("Cross correlation")+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))+
    theme_bw()+ 
    theme(legend.position = "none", 
          plot.title = element_text(size=10))+
    ggtitle(title) -> p

  ggsave(paste(title, ".jpg"), plot = p, height = 2.7, width = 4, units = "in")
}     
# The only thing I originally changed from the source code was ".svg" to ".jpg", 
# "theme_economist()" to "theme_bw()" and colors.

# run the function
xcf_plot(df = hydro, x = hydro$big, y = hydro$mangum, title = "big and mangum")
```

Error Message:

> Error in ifelse(x.corr > 0, "green", "red") : object 'x.corr' not
>   found

Any idea why this occurring? This is especially weird because I was able to use this exact same code previously and it worked flawlessly:

[image: flawlessly].

Here's my session info:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30),
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit),
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)
```

Comment: Hey! Everything works fine on my Windows machine. Seems to be some troubles during your R-session. Did you try to restart R?
Also run this code without function. It may help you to understand where is the problem. One more thing, maybe there is a missing values in your original dataset?

Comment: @Alex: works for me too. If restart your R session doesn't help, try updating `R`, `dplyr` & `ggplot2` to the latest versions

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Tung was right- it needed an update. I thought it had to be something like that because the code worked and then didn't work the next time. Thanks for the quick response!